# Determining an element's absolute on-document position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to determine the exact on-screen coordinates (relative to document) of an HTML element.

I already have code that does this (summing clientWidth and clientHeight of each parent object up to the root), but seemed to be ineffective when jQuery's scroll effect comes into work.

The elements I need to detect the position of, in fact, are part of a `div` with `overflow="hidden"` that is used for jQuery scrolling effect.

When I try to get the element's position with the current code, I get a width value that is relative to the length of the scrollable panel. When I scroll the panel, the position **remains the same** (so, the tooltip I ultimately need to position is placed too right, in the exact position the anchor control is when hidden behind the container panel's overflow.

#### My question is

How to adapt the current code to this requirement?

```
function findPos(obj) {

    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return [curleft, curtop];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) function.

Comment: I tried to read the documentation on the API website you pointed. It seems by numbers (from second example) that offset is relative to parent. So this doesn't solve the problem... :(

Comment: @djechelon: read carefully. You're mixing up `.offset()` with [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position). The `.offset()` function returns the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, **relative to the document.**

Comment: Hmm... maybe the test boxes are in iframes... (I checked the source HTML and couldn't find the [i]frame tag))

Comment: No, the webage you linked. I just found in the second example that it returns "0,0" for the first div while it's not on top-left of browser screen, and that is my concern

Comment: By the way, that function seems to ROCK anyway ;) Accepting in a few mins

Answer (score 1):

As Matt points out, its wise to use a Frameworks function for that, because it is cross-browser compatible and fixes various issues through different versions.

Besides that, i hope you refer to "screen" as the currend shown document in your browser and not the actual computer-screen/display, because that would quite impossible.

Comment: I cant comment on other people so i hope someone reads it here:
the second example in the jQuery docs makes use of an iframe, the grey box you can see is the iframe's area.