# Get correct order of tr-elements as jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In your source code you can define tfoot before tbody but in the browser tfoot will still be displayed last:

```
<table>
   <thead><tr><th>i get displayed first</th></tr></thead>
   <tfoot><tr><td>i get displayed last</td></tr></tfoot>
   <tbody><tr><td>i get displayed second</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I want to grab the tr elements of this table in their visual order, not the order they have in the html. So this of course does not do the trick:

```
var rows = $('table tr');
```

jQuery goes through the table and adds the tr elements in the order they appear in the source code.

I thought I could make separate blocks and concatenate them to get the right order:

```
var header = $('table>thead>tr');
var body = $('table>tbody>tr');
var footer = $('table>tfoot>tr');

var rows = $().add(header).add(body).add(footer);
```

Strangely enough the order is still the same as if I did `$('table tr')`! How can this be?

I've also illustrated the problem in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nerdess/sKewX/2/

Comment: var rows = $([header[0],body[0],footer[0]]); ?

Comment: thanks @lexmihaylov, your post is the right answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the elements in the exact order you want, you need to build the result manually. I've modified your code in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lechlukasz/sKewX/3/

```
var header = $('table>thead>tr');
var body = $('table>tbody>tr');
var footer = $('table>tfoot>tr');

var apppend = function(arr, items) {
    for (var i=0;i<items.lenght;i++)
        arr.push(items[i])
}
var rows = []
append(rows, header)
append(rows, body)
append(rows, footer)

console.log(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Element selectors look at the DOM, so they will only return the elements in the order they appear in the DOM.

If you want them in the VISUAL order you'll have to determine the positioning of each item yourself.

See: [Determining an element's absolute on-document position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408150/determining-an-elements-absolute-on-document-position)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation for add() method:

> Do not assume that this method appends the elements to the existing
>   collection in the order they are passed to the .add() method. When all
>   elements are members of the same document, the resulting collection
>   from .add() will be sorted in document order; that is, in order of
>   each element's appearance in the document. If the collection consists
>   of elements from different documents or ones not in any document, the
>   sort order is undefined. To create a jQuery object with elements in a
>   well-defined order, use the $(array_of_DOM_elements) signature.

So yes, it will appear the same as `$('table tr');`

Comment: d'oh, should've read the add() documentation more carefully, thanks! your answer pointed me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('table tr')` will only look for code (it has nothing to do with the console).

Now because you add the `body` to `var rows` before you add the `footer`, it is logical that the display will be different from the code.

It's the same as publishing a book and then telling the readers to read `page 3` before `page 2`:

Now the readers ('the console') know the correct order, but the book still retains a wrong order of page numbers.

So to make life easy: try to keep code and display as parallel as possible. Hence try to keep the same order in both to avoid unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the `insertion sort` algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).  By design, `add()` collects the elements in the DOM order.
The idea is to sort the elements based on how they'd be seen visually (using their `offset`).
JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pv4tj/